# Javascript - How can I change scope and access method without 'this'

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, dom-manipulation

I want to port [domjs](https://github.com/medikoo/domjs) for browser.

```
var mytemplate = function () {
  header(
    h1('Heading'),
    h2('Subheading'));

  nav(
    ul({ 'class': 'breadcrumbs' },
      li(a({ href: '/' }, 'Home')),
      li(a({ href: '/section/'}, 'Section')),
      li(a('Subject'))));

  article(
    p('Lorem ipsum...'));

  footer('Footer stuff');
};
```

But I don't know how to attach some methods like 'header' 'h1' 'h2' to 'mytemplate'.

How can I use header() without 'this' keyword.

---

Failed Case:

```
   template.apply($funcs),
   template.bind($funcs)(),
   template.call($funcs),
```

I can't use header(), in template. (In this case, 'this.header' was available)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check the [documentation](https://github.com/medikoo/domjs#usage):

```
var domjs = require('domjs/lib/html5')(document);
// Execute mytemplate with h1, h2 etc. functions attached
var mydom = domjs.build(mytemplate);
console.log(mydom.firstChild.nodeName); // header
```

If you're asking how does it work (?) as you have some custom handling in mind - 
It works by polluting the global scope for the time of function being called. You can see how it's done here -> https://github.com/medikoo/domjs/blob/v0.2.3/lib/dscope.js#L32-L36

btw. at all times you can access all those functions on `domjs.map` as `domjs.map.header`, `domjs.map.h1` etc.

Method of using global scope, is controversial and has it's downsides (e.g. functions are not available after function returns) and in upcoming version of domjs this method would no longer be used. As an alternative [Webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake) (and possibly [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)) plugins would be provided, so domjs templates can be bundled with those functions assured in local scope, then things will work natural way.